# Bad Request React Axios 400

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, http-status-code-400, bad-request

Can Anyone tell me why I am having this error??

the error is status code 400 bad request

This could be on the server?

I am new with react

```
handleSubmit(event, _success, _error) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = {
      FriendlyName: this.state.FriendlyName,
      full_name: this.state.full_name,
      email: this.state.email,
    };

    const config = {
      method: 'post',
      url:
        'https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/{<WorkerSid>}/Workers',
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Basic QUM1MmNiOTIxNGQwY2ZmMjA4NjBiZDdjMTQ5Y2Q4NjBlNTpmODRmOWJiOGFlZjI4MWFmZDY2NGY4NTY1OGYwNzJhOA==',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: data,
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('data', data);
        if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
          if (typeof _success === 'function') _success(data);
        } else {
          if (typeof _error === 'function')
            _error({ error: 'Não houve nenhum retorno.' });
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the value of the `data` variable. Could you show the value of a log of data?

Answer (score 0):

Try backticks instead of apostrophe `url:'https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/{<WorkerSid>}/Workers'`

```
const config = {
      method: 'post',
      url:
        'https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/{<WorkerSid>}/Workers',
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Basic QUM1MmNiOTIxNGQwY2ZmMjA4NjBiZDdjMTQ5Y2Q4NjBlNTpmODRmOWJiOGFlZjI4MWFmZDY2NGY4NTY1OGYwNzJhOA==',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: data,
    };
```